# The five letter word

Tags: riddle, mathematics, word, knowledge, wordplay

> I will absorb everything, in some of your jewelries.
>
> People call me the highest, only to some proper me.
>
> Modulo by the highest me, there are so few trees.
>
> Modulo by me being 2357, there is decimal number 383.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> an [IDEAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)),

which is indeed a five-letter word as the title says.

*I will absorb everything, in some of your jewelries.*

> The definition of an ideal is a subset of a **ring** ("jewellery") such that when multiplied by any element of the ring, it remains the same set ("absorbing").

*People call me the highest, only to some proper me.*

> A **maximal ideal** is the largest possible *proper* ideal within the ring.

*Modulo by the highest me, there are so few trees.*

> The quotient of a ring by its maximal ideal is a **field**.

*Modulo by me being 2357, there is decimal number 383.*

> The quotient of a ring by a **prime ideal** (2, 3, 5, 7 being primes) is an **integral domain** (which probably connects to 383 in some way?)

Comment: Correct! Great job.

Comment: For the 383, rot13(Vg ersref gb gur vagrteny flzoby nf va vagrtengvba, juvpu vf n fgergpurq F, urapr "ybat F", erfhygvat va havpbqr punenpgre H+017S. (Qrpvzny cbvag 383)) Too much wordplay, huh?

Comment: @DannyuNDos Ahaaa, I should have thought of that. Good one.